# Force ASP.NET clean compile

Tags: asp.net

How can you force ASP.NET 1.1 to recompile its runtimes as in the ASP.NET Temporary Files location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be reading WAYYY to deeply into this problem, but if you are having problems with references just in case it helps try this:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200221042258/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/shahed/archive/2006/11/16/97240.aspx)

Although disabling batch compilation is a performance hit.

Comment: Actually this was my exact problem... this is the perfect blog post to explain to me, i was using the batch="false", but i like the idea of the precompiled page!!!  thanks.  rep up and answer!

Answer (score 6):

To force a rebuild make a change to the web.config file (something as simple as a newline is enough) this forces a recompile.

Answer (score 1):

Shutdown IIS (make sure the wpworker procs are killed), blow away the WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\Temporary ASP.NET Files and blow away any dlls in your own bin directory.  Once you restart IIS it'll rebuild.

Comment: I was looking for an easier less intrusive way to do this... I am already doing this.  I can't shutdown IIS on a production box.

Comment: For anyone who's having re-compilation issues with IIS this is a handy "last ditch" way of fixing them.